# v2.ODataModel: which API is more preferred? "bindElement" or "read"?

Tags: sapui5

I set the `view.setModel(model)`, get the model for the view, and request for `model.read("/entitySet('10000')")`. 
The model is then filled up with `/entitySet('10000')/properties`.

But it is difficult to assign them to view fields, as now in the view, `<Text text="{property}">` doesn't work. It has to be `<Text text="{/entitySet('10000')/property}">`.

On the other hand, if I set view's context binding to `"/entitySet('10000')"`, then `<Text text="{property}">` would start working.

Which one is the preferred method? When to use `.read`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I almost never use `.read` if I want to use the results from an OData call directly in a binding context. The only time I use `.read` is if I want to manipulate the results before doing anything with them.

Look at this example from the sdk for instance: https://ui5.sap.com/#/entity/sap.ui.table.Table/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.OData

Syntax on this kind of binding is similar to read but with a few differences in events, and a few different types of methods depending on what you want to bind. Binding to a view for instance uses `bindElement`:

```js
 this.getView().bindElement("/entitySet('1000')");
```

After this, fields on that particular entity *can* be accessed as `<Text text="{property}" />`.

Here's an example from one of my current apps with events and some other call parameters:

```js
this.getView().bindElement({
  path: `/Orders('${currentOrderNumber}')`,
  parameters: {
    expand: 'Texts'
  },
  events: {
    dataRequested: _ => this.getView().setBusy(true),
    dataReceived: data => {
      if (!this.getView().getBindingContext()) {
        // navigate to `Not Found` view
      }
    },
    change: _ => this.getView().setBusy(false)
  }
});
```

For a table, it's slightly different, since it depends on the aggregation you wish to bind, such as

```js
oTable.bindRows({
  path: "properties"
});
```

Which is the same as:

```xml
<Table rows="{properties}" />
```

Answer (score 3):

It's always important to be more expressive. Use the API that is specifically designed to do that one task.

Comparing the two variants:

1. `myModel.read(sPath)` with `text="{/path/property}"`
2. `myControl.bindElement(sPath)` with `text="{property}"`

I'd be perplexed about the 1st call whereas in the 2nd call, I'd know exactly what you want to achieve (You want to *bind element*. Alternatively, [`bindObject`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject#methods/bindObject) can be also used).

The same applies to the framework. Since you're telling exactly what you want to achieve, the framework can improve its behavior based on your intent. **E.g.:** in `(route)PatternMatched` handler when the user navigates to the same page, `.bindElement` with the same path won't trigger another request since the model already stored the entity from the previous call. It can show the result immediately.
With `.read`, however, the framework doesn't know what you want to achieve, so it sends the request right away regardless of the application state.

Additionally, the 1st variant is anything but future-proof. It relies on the cached results. It's almost a side-effect that it works at all. The problem is that there is no guarantee that this behavior will continue to work in later versions. Also **there won't be `read` method in V4 ODataModel.**

---

## TL;DR

### ```js
v2.ODataModel#read
```

- Does **not** create `context` from the response. Repeating `.read("<same path>")` always sends a new request.
- Less expressive. Encourages app developers to work with a client-side model (e.g. JSONModel).
- Application loses context awareness, increasing TCO, less future-proof.

### ```js
bindElement or bindObject
```

- Creates `context` from the response and stores it internally so that the same request can return the data immediately.
- Clearly expresses the intent; application as well as framework can work with the existing APIs.
- More future-proof: `v4.ODataModel` does **not** support manual read. Imagine you've built your applications with the `v2ODataModel.read`-`jsonModel.setData` approach, and you need to migrate to `v4`. Have fun. :)

---

I honestly think that `v2.ODataModel#read` should have never become a public method. I wouldn't encourage anyone to use `.read` **except of** when reading the `$count` value manually.

If the entity values need to be formatted, there are formatters and binding types out of the box which are also easy to extend.

If the application needs to restructure the response body, usually it's a sign of a poor design of the data model or the service not conforming to the OData spec.

Answer (score -1):

I almost agree with Jorg, but not entirely:

It really depends on what are you trying to achieve. If looking to display data from backend then the easiest way to go is with `this.getView().bindElement()`

but if you are in need to manipulate data before displaying (like formatting text, displaying images from base64 strings, etc) OR if you would like to create new entity using some of existing data, OR update the existing data - the `this.getModel(sName).read()` is the way to go - as you can set read entity with all its deep entities  to JSONModel in successCallback and manipulate it from the localModel.

If using localModel the dataBinding is pretty much the same in the view - except you have to additionally give model name to take data from. So for example, if in successCallback of your Model.read() you set your data to Model named "localModel":

```
this.getModel().read(sObjectPath, {
            urlParameters: {
                $expand: ""
            },
            success: function (oData) {
              // "localModel" is name you gave in onInit function to your new JSONMOdel, when setting it to View e.g. this.getView().setModel(oJSONMOdel, "localModel")
               this.getModel("localModel").setData(oData);
            } 
          })
```

then in XML view you would indicate that

```
<Text text="{localModel>/mainPropertyName}"/>
// for displaying deep entities as List items or in Table
<List items="{localModel>/deepEntityName}">
 <StandardListItem title="{localModel>propertyNamefromDeepEntity}" />
</List>
```

From my experience working with more complex apps that Read-Only - I always use Model.read().

Comment: I have to disagree on your first point Shanir. If you need to manipulate data before displaying it, there are much easier ways to do this with types and formatters. This removes the need to build some custom read and model synchronisation code - just let UI5 handle that for you.The additional benefit is that it forces you structure your code into formatters which just handle data conversion and are very unit testable.

Comment: I guess I wasn't explicit what I meant - I didn't mean simple property formatting, like Date or conditional coloring, but more complex where you have to format dynamic properties, work with dynamic filters to format tree tables or other complex structures. 
I don't think that anyone who suggests binding view has actually developed smth more complex that  read-only apps, at least 3 months earlier working directly with oData had so annoying behavior! And anyone who have struggled with client requirements will tell the same. even complex SAP standard APPS use local models, and that tells a LOT!